# select query to get results of meta_key

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a custom field name "front_sl_slider". I want to display all the posts that have custom field "front_sl_slider" value set to 1. also, i want to display, thumbnail, title, and other custom fields data for the posts that i get as result of my query.

```
$meta_pages = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT *    FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE  post_type = 'page' AND  meta_key = 'front_sl_slider' AND meta_value = 1 ORDER BY menu_order", 'OBJECT'); 
    if ( $meta_pages ) 
        {
        foreach ( $meta_pages as $pageChild1 ) : setup_postdata( $pageChild1 );
         echo get_post_meta($pageChild1->ID, 'front_sl_slider', true);
         echo get_post_meta($pageChild1->ID, 'project_client_name', true) ."<br>";
         echo get_post_meta($pageChild1->ID, 'project_architect', true) ."<br>"; 
        endforeach; 
        }
```

Comment: Your select query is wrong for that. Please consult the codex for the database structure and build your query with a tool like phpmyadmin or adminer first, so you actually know if it can work or not. Some work I would expect you to do before asking the question. Everything else is just guessing, not programming. This site is about programming. So please give your question some love.

Comment: Can you please give your table structure? Is there a column called `front_sl_slider`?

Comment: @mathematical.coffee: Table structure is that of wordpress. You find it in codex, see my previous comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$querystr = "   SELECT $wpdb->posts.* , $wpdb->postmeta.*
                        FROM $wpdb->posts, $wpdb->postmeta
                        WHERE $wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id 
                        AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = 'Featured_Projects_Page' 
                        AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value = 1 
                        AND $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'page'
                        ORDER BY $wpdb->posts.post_date DESC
                     ";
$pageposts = $wpdb->get_results($querystr, OBJECT);
```

try this, this should work.